# Override back button windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an app in windows phone 7.8 which opens a webpage in it. I have to navigate inside that page.

I want that while pressing the back button, it goes back inside that webpage but each time I press it, the app closes.

How can I modify the behaviour of that button? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WP7, you can't access the control's navigation history, so you may well need to implement it yourself.  I'd porobably do something like this.

1 Handle the navigated event in the control, and each time you visit a page, push the Uri onto a stack of Uris.
2 On the back key press, if there is more than 1 Uri in the stack (i.e. more than the initially loaded page) navigate to the previous URI (since we can't go back, fake it by navigating forward to the previous page...)
3 If we are at the first entry in the stack, let the system handle the button press.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WB1.Navigated += WB1_Navigated;
}

Stack<Uri> visitedUrls = new Stack<Uri>();

void WB1_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    visitedUrls.Push(e.Uri);
}

protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (visitedUrls.Count > 1)
    {
        WB1.Navigate(visitedUrls.Pop());
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Note that this is far from perfect, and won't handle form resubmissions, for example.

In WP8, you would check whether the browser's navigation stack allows you to go back.  If it does, go back and cancel the button press.  If not, let the system handle the back button for you.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (myBrowserInstance.CanGoBack)
    {
        myBrowserInstance.GoBack();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my webbrowser declaration:  <phone:WebBrowser Name="WB1" />
but if I use WB1 insead myBrowserInstance, it gives me an error about the methods, telling that they don't exist

Comment: OK, it may be a difference between WP7 and WP8 that I wasn't previously aware of.  Let me take a look.

Comment: Updated with a quick and dirty possibility to handle your case.

Comment: Man, It doesn't work. I don't know what happends... When I press the back button, the app doesn't close (so, something is happening) But it doesn't go back. Sometimes it reloads the same page. Maybe is it because the webpage is created by jquery mobile?

Comment: I tried with google.com insteas my webpage and happends the same thing. navigating to some webs, when pressing back button, it reloads the same page

Comment: Ah, that's because of a glaring error in my code.  You'll probably need to pop 2 items off the stack and navigate to the second one.

Comment: Well, using 2 pops instead one it works with normal webpages. Not with mine. I don't know why. Maybe it is because of jquery mobile. But, if this is the only way and it doesn't work, I will have to look for another way to make my program.

Thanks for your time. Since this solution works and you help me, I will set it as the correct one. I guess it will help other people with normal webpages. Thanks a lot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38849/discussion-between-biribu-and-zombiesheep)

Answer (score 1):

Remember to `Cancel` the event call in this way:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // your code 

     e.Cancel = true; 
}
```

As ARM suggested, be careful when using this. According to Microsoft, if you press the back key, when you are in the first page, the app must close. So do not use this override on the first page.

Comment: @Biribu This is the correct method of doing what you want but there is one gotchya to it. If you modify the phones hardware functions TO much a uptight certifier might fail your submission. They have their rules laid out but it is at their descretion whether you're violating them or not.

Comment: I get an error with CancelEventArgs:

Error 1 The type or namespace name 'CancelEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\xampp\htdocs\WindowsPhone\WindowsPush\WindowsPush\MainPage.xaml.cs 188 48 WindowsPush

Comment: And, how can I control if I am on the first page or not? The webpage cannot return anything to make the app knows that

Comment: I edited my previous post, please tell me if it works. I can't help you with that. It's up to you to know how your app works and, according to that, you have to detect on which page the user actually is.

Comment: Now it tells the same about componentModel. Should I include another library or so?

Comment: Maybe I am including the code in the wrong place. Where do I have to put it exactly? I am doing inside MainPage file

Comment: It's System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onbackkeypress%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Where do I have to import this packet?

Comment: Just replace ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs with System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs

Comment: Ok, now it does something. But not fine. It just try to go back to the same webpage. But not the previous. I know that the webpage works because I have tested in android and in webbrowser in my computer.